# Asus sometimes boot problems

Tags: indicator, asus, battery, fan

Usually my Asus notebook boots like it should. All drivers are working, everything runs smooth and I don't have any problems.

However, sometimes it starts with my fan at 100%, and the battery indicator (on the front of my notebook) is blinking orange. The fan stays at 100% until I power off my notebook, take out the battery and put it back in again. So does the battery indicator. Also, the battery indicator applet in Ubuntu reports a wrong battery status (percentage) when this happens.

I never had these problems with Windows, and this starts as soon I choose Ubuntu from GRUB.

Does anyone know what the cause is and how I can fix it?